# systemd-networkd: Updating statically assigned ipv6 prefix

Tags: networking, ip, ipv6, systemd

I want to be able to change my statically assigned ipv6 address prefix in my systemd-networkd configuration file without rebooting my entire system. For example if I entered the following in a file `/etc/systemd/network/10-ens33.network`:

```
[Match]
Name=ens33

[Network]
Address=2001:db8:1212:1211::/63
```

Then to get my configuration to apply run the following: `sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd`
now when I run `ip addr show` the following prints:

```
2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:f8:f8:18 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s1
    inet6 2001:db8:1212:1211::/63 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Realizing I've made a typo and actually want an ipv6 prefix of `/64` I go to edit my file `/etc/systemd/network/10-ens33.network` to the following:

```
[Match]
Name=ens33

[Network]
Address=2001:db8:1212:1211::/64
```

However this time when I run `sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd` my change hasn't taken and I get the exact same output from running `ip addr show`.

The only way I know how to get a prefix change to take is to reboot the system however I'm hoping there's an easier way that doesn't involve a system reboot and that I'm just missing some configuration or something.